# Using exceptions within a boost::thread thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I began to play around with boost::threads, but I'm kind of stuck with this problem:

I don't understand why this program crashes as soon as the exception is thrown, because I try to catch it within the thread. I thought that it would be possible to work with exceptions as long as the handling happens in the same thread as the throwing ?

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

void doWork();
void thrower();

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
 boost::thread worker(doWork);
 worker.join();
 return 0;
}

void doWork(){
 try{
    thrower();
 }
 catch( const exception &e ){
  //handle exception
 }
}
void thrower(){
 // program terminates as soon as the exception is thrown
 throw exception();
}
```

Additional information:

*Using MinGW32
*Boost v.1.44
*Linking dynamically against the multithread debug dll Version of the thread lib

Comment: This won't even compile without proper forward declarations and `using namespace std`. But if I add those, it works fine on Ubuntu Linux w/ Boost 1.40.

Comment: sorry, this is a reduced version of the code, to display the problem. Did you link statically or dynamically ?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Mac OS X using Boost 1.44 dynamically linked.

Comment: thank you for testing, this leaves me puzzeld what to do next. I've been trying every compiler/linker option I could find to get this damm little thing to run

Comment: @zitroneneis: Does the g++ used to build the Boost.Threads library have the same ABI as the g++ you used to build your program?

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca: I used the same compiler when I compiled the library as I use now to compile the program. I don't have any problems with other boost libraries that had to be compiled. I have worked with system,filesystem,iostreams and program options and have never had a problem like this. But I could link them statically, which I can't do with the thread library, because it will result in Linker errors

Comment: @sellibitze: fixed, but I'm quite shure now, that the problem hasn't got anything to do with the code I posted. Something is wrong with my boost::thread library. I just can't figure out whar, because the library itself compiles without errors. But as I said before, linking statically is't possible because of link errors, linking dynamically is possible, but the program terminates as soon as a exception is thrown (see above code)

Comment: What are the static link errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:
it's a bug in the boost library that only occurs when working with a minGW Version newer than 3.17. [Boost trac ticket #4258](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4258)

After applying the suggested workaround, and setting the Preprocessor Definition **BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB** I am now able to link against the static library, and I can work with exceptions, as long as they're caught in the same thread that throws them.

Tank you very much for your comments

Answer (score 0):

In applications consisting out of multiple shared libraries you might have to be very careful wrt the visibility of your exceptions. gcc does not make the RTTI information for exceptions visible from the outside of a shared library by default, causing exceptions thrown across shared library boundaries 'disappear'. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for a detailed description and possible pitfalls.

Certainly I can't be sure you're facing this problem, but from what you describe it's a possibility.

Comment: wow, thats interesting stuff. Fortunately for me this wasn't the problem in my case. Thank you very much for the idea anyway